# Read and split undefined strings from txt file in C

Tags: c, file, split, strtok

```
FILE *file;
char text[R];
char *splitter;
fgets(text,R,file);
splitter =strtok(text," ,.-;");
while (splitter!=NULL)
{
    printf("%s\n",splitter);
    splitter=strtok(NULL," ,.-;");
}
```

The txt file says:

```
Hello lad,
how are you
doing
```

(this is a random text I wrote for testing)

This code will only split the "hello lad" and won't move up to the next line.
I could do it with arrays but the exercise is to read a random txt by the user so I have undefined lines and strings per line.
Can somebody give any hints?
One of my thoughts was to count lines and strings but I wanted another opinion first...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only call `fgets` once, so you only ever read a single line of text.

You need to loop over calls to `fgets` until there's nothing left.

```
while (fgets(text,R,file)) {
    splitter =strtok(text," ,.-;");
    while (splitter!=NULL)
    {
       printf("%s\n",splitter);
        splitter=strtok(NULL," ,.-;");
    }
}
```